# How to specify structure of arrays in glVertexAttribPointer call in OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm working on an iOS project and I want to know if it's possible to pass to OpenGL the vertex data as a structure of arrays instead of an array of structures. Currently this is how I's trying but I'm not sure if I did something wrong or just this is not the way to pass the data. When I run the app it doesn't show anything.

Initially I had only the positions array without the structure and everything worked just fine, but now I also need the normals in order to calculate lighting. I thought I might be able to do it like this instead of having to create a new vertex structure and parse all data into that structure.

The structure I'm using:

```
typedef struct _component {
    float *positions;
    float *normals;
} Component;
```

Setting the attributes:

```
        Component *comp = (Component*)malloc(sizeof(Component));
        comp->positions = objects[k][i].mesh.positions.data();
        comp->normals = objects[k][i].mesh.normals.data();

        [self setupVBOs:i objectComponent:objects[k][i] structure:comp];

        glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        WT_GL_ASSERT(glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot));
        glVertexAttribPointer(_normalsSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &comp->normals);
        WT_GL_ASSERT(glEnableVertexAttribArray(_normalsSlot));
```

And the binding method:

```
- (void)setupVBOs:(int)i objectComponent:(tinyobj::shape_t)component structure:(Component*)comp {
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size()*2, comp, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * component.mesh.indices.size(), component.mesh.indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with buffers and openGL you need to first understand that this is all designed for speed so there are no sense checks here and openGL will try to process pretty much anything and the result might quickly lead to bad access.

When using buffers you will have 2 steps. First you will reserve a memory for the GPU buffer and send the data to that buffer and then later you will tell the openGL how to actually use those data.

So the first step does not really have any type, you will only tell it a size of the buffer and then give it a `void` pointer and a size saying "copy whatever you find in the memory at this address". The method you use is:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size()*2, comp, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

So here you are saying so want an array buffer that has twice the size of number of floating values in your position buffer multiplied by the number of bytes contained in a single float. That sounds about right as long as the number of dimensions for position is the same as number of dimensions for the normal (which might not always be the case). So the size seems fine your case at least. But then you input the address of `comp` which is the address of the structure holding 2 more pointers and is totally wrong. So your fix was using `(*comp)->positions` which is actually not needed, a single pointer would be enough in the method and the result would be `comp->positions` which is now a pointer to your actual position buffer on the CPU. But by using this you did not ensure that the normal buffer pointer is set correctly so the actual size is wrong. At this point you assume that your operating system had actually reserved the normal buffer right after the position buffer; so you assume that

`(comp->normals - comp->positions) = sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size()`

which might be true in most cases if the 2 allocation calls ware made one after another. But your OS might assign this buffers to any point in the memory as it sees fit and this check will fail in some cases and might produce bad access or simply copy some random data to the buffer.

So this is a pretty big flaw and there are two ways of fixing it. The straight forward way is to create 2 array buffers. Since you have a separate buffer for each the position and the normal data it makes sense to create 2 array buffers on the GPU as well:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexPositionBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexPositionBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size(), comp->positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexNormalBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexNormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.normals.size(), comp->normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

By doing it so you also need to bind the correct buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer`, which you should do anyway. At the moment the correct buffer is simply already bound from the method call when you copy the data.

Then the other procedure is to generate the single buffer which is large enough to hold both of the arrays. But then this means you will need to create a buffer and then copy each of your vertex data one by one. To do so you need to use the sub buffer methods:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * (component.mesh.positions.size()+component.mesh.normals.size()), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Note that by sending `NULL` no data copying will be done at this moment. Now to copy the data:

```
  glBufferSubData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size(), comp->positions)
  glBufferSubData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size(), sizeof(float) * component.mesh.normals.size(), comp->normals)
```

I hope this code speaks for itself. You specify where in the buffer to write, how much to write and what to write.

**So now that we have the data on the openGL buffers:**

We need to tell the openGL how to use them for which you use `glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);`.

- The first argument is a link to the shader handle and is OK.
- The second is a number of dimensions which you hardcoded as 3 and
  seems OK as well.
- Then the interesting argument is an enumeration
  where you used `GL_FLOAT` and is a very important parameter as with it the openGL can typecast the buffer so it is used as a `float*` although the data were inserted as `void*`. But more importantly it corresponds to the CPU type called `GLFloat` which should be used as a primitive type when defining your vertex data on the GPU. If you look at the definition of the `GLFloat` it will probably say that is is defined as `float` in your version but technically you could have a version where `GLFloat` was defined as a `long float` or `double` where then the `GL_FLOAT` would treat a single element as 64bit primitive instead of 32bit again producing a bad access. So it will always work in your case but if possible try to be consistent and use the primitives which are designed for the API you are using (`GLFloat`, `GLInt`, `GLByte`...).
- The normalization parameter is OK here
- The stride should be specified if possible. The zero value is a shortcut and is then computed as a tightly packed data array by using the second and third parameter: The stride is then `3*sizof(GLFloat)`. Why this is important is for instance you have a shape which you want to draw as a 2D object simply discarding the `Z` component then you would simply set 2 dimensions instead of 3. But since the data structure is persistent then the stride would be `2*sizeof(GLFloat)` and the drawing would be wrong. So again in your case it will work but try to avoid such implementations. BTW this value is a number of bytes between 2 sequential values. So since the next position is right after the current one then this is `3*sizof(GLFloat)`.

  - And the last one is the actual relative pointer in the buffer. For the position that means `(void *)NULL` (0 works as well here) and as someone might tell you the `(void *)0` is actually more correct then the `(void *)NULL`. Then the normal buffer starts exactly as you set it when transferring the data using sub buffer and is `(void *)(sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size())`. Or in the case of 2 buffers it is simply `(void *)0` again.

This should be all considering the fixes you need and to make the program stable. There are some other concerns here though: The buffer is meant to be filled once and use many time. That means you should not copy the data on every draw call so the `setupVBOs` should be a part of initialization, after that you only bind the buffer and set the attributes whenever you need it. Also some times there is no need for the buffers at all and simply send the CPU pointer to the attribute and you will lose all of the buffer code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, comp->positions);
glVertexAttribPointer(_normalsSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, comp->normals);
```

This procedure seems more friendly for your data structure but the array buffers should gain performance (assuming you do not generate them every draw call).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I used your second approach and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make this work. These are the changes I made in case someone has the same problem.

```
        Component *comp = (Component*)malloc(sizeof(Component));
        comp->positions = objects[k][i].mesh.positions.data();
        comp->normals = objects[k][i].mesh.normals.data();

        [self setupVBOs:i objectComponent:objects[k][i] structure:&comp];

        glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        WT_GL_ASSERT(glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot));
        glVertexAttribPointer(_normalsSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)sizeof(comp->positions));
        WT_GL_ASSERT(glEnableVertexAttribArray(_normalsSlot));
```

Looks like I was passing the offset in wrong way and also when passing the structure as parameter it has to be double pointer and then differantiate it with an asterisk (*). The trick is that positions is the starting point in the struct so it acts as the pointer of the struct. Then the offset is the size of the first array since the normals array starts right after positions array. The stride has to be 0 so that it will always be relative to the beginning of the buffer.

```
- (void)setupVBOs:(int)i objectComponent:(tinyobj::shape_t)component structure:(Component **)comp {
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * component.mesh.positions.size() * 2, (*comp)->positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * component.mesh.indices.size(), component.mesh.indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Comment: This is very wrong. Your code will fail sooner or later as the assumptions here are way too great. For instance when you copy the vertex data to the buffer you assume that the 2 buffers in the component class are allocated exactly one after another. Fill up a memory a bit so the system tries to free it up a bit and this will not be the case. You will get an exception for reading a memory that is not yours. Anyway you can use null on buffer data and then use glBufferSubData to transfer the 2 arrays separately to the buffer. But unfortunately much more is wrong.

Comment: @MaticOblak You are right, at some point I get bad access exception...I'm not an expert in this. I would appreciate if you would try to be more constructive and provide more details, and probably the answer to the question. Would be helpful if you could provide some code. Thanks.